# If series is absolutely convergent then $\sum \limits_{n\in I}a_n=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}a_n.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is absolutely convergent and let $I\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $I=\bigsqcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k$. Then show that $$\sum \limits_{n\in I}a_n=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}a_n. \qquad (*)$$

I don't have any idea how to solve it.

I do know that in any absolute convergent series permutation of terms does not change the sum and I guess it should be used somehow in order to prove equality $(*)$.

Can anyone show the rigorous proof of equality $(*)$, please?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence) is a proof. [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Manipulation_of_Absolutely_Convergent_Series/Permutation) is another.

Comment: What's the definition of summation here?

Comment: @Masacroso, link which you provided have not nothing in common with my question. I do know that in absolute convergent series any permutation does not change the sum.

Comment: @ZFR you had written "I do know that in any absolute convergent series permutation of terms does not change the sum. But I want to prove it rigorously and cannot do it." Hence my comment providing two formal proofs. Make clear your question please.

Comment: @Masacroso, sorry about that. Done

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem? If so consider the sequence $b_{n,k} = a_n \mathbf{1}\{n \in I_k\}$.

Comment: Your equality is equivalent to this other $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}a_n=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}a_{\sigma (n)}$ for an arbitrary permutation $\sigma $ in $\mathbb N $, to see this just use the definition of series as a limit of partial sums. Now a rigorous proof of one of the directions of the equality is in the first link that I put in my first comment. In the same link, prior to the proof, there is a comment about how to prove the converse direction using the Riemann rearrangement theorem, you can just use the contrapositive statement of this theorem.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, Not yet. I am learning measure theory and this question arises from one of the problems which I am solving. Do you know the proof without Fubini's theorem?

Comment: ok, there is a complication with the traced route of my previous comment: it is not true that the equality of this question is equivalent to this one $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}a_n=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}a_{\sigma (n)}$ if the cardinality of some of the $I_k$ is infinite. From a simple proof but that need some more theoretic background we can use Fubini's theorem as @stochasticboy commented before. I dont know, at this moment, an elementary proof.

Comment: @Masacroso, I said that I don't know Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Another way.  First, prove it in case $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.  Then in general, use $a_n = a_n^+ - a_n^-$.

Comment: It's past my bedtime anyway, so instead of going on with my attempt at an answer, I'll just make some comments. @stochasticboy321's comment doesn't require measure theory, only something like Theorem 8.42 in Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis* (2nd ed. 1974). Or, one could use the big gun of proposition (5.3.6) in Dieudonne, *Foundations of Modern Analysis* (1969), or Theorem 9.51 of Protter & Morrey, *A First Course in Real Analysis* (2nd ed. 1991) (but the proof of the latter result is left to the reader).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, if you have an answer i would be happy to read it, please. I was not able to find question on MSE so it should be nice to see your answer. I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that $a_n \ge 0$ and define $\sum_{n \in I} a_n = \sup_{J \subset I, J \text{ finite}} \sum_{n \in J} a_n$. Note that it follows that if $I \subset I'$ then
$\sum_{n \in I} a_n  \le \sum_{n \in I'} a_n$.

From https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3680889/27978 we see that if
$K = K_1 \cup \cdots \cup K_m$, a disjoint union, then 
$\sum_{n \in K} a_n = \sum_{n \in K_1} a_n + \cdots + \sum_{n \in K_m} a_n$.

Since $I'=I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_m \subset I$ we see that
$\sum_{n \in I} a_n \ge \sum_{n \in I'} a_n  = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n$. It follows that
$\sum_{n \in I} a_n \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n$. This is the
'easy' direction.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then there is some finite $J \subset I$ such that
$\sum_{n\in J} a_n > \sum_{n \in I} a_n -\epsilon$. Since $J$ is finite and the $I_k$ are pairwise disjoint we have $J \subset I'=I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_m$
for some $m$ and so
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n \ge \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{n \in I_k} a_n  \ge \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{n \in J \cap I_k} a_n = \sum_{n\in J} a_n > \sum_{n \in I} a_n -\epsilon$.

(It is not relevant here, but a small proof tweak shows that the result holds true even if the $a_n$ do not have a finite sum.)

Now suppose we have $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{n \in I} |a_n|  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ is finite.
We need to define what we mean by $\sum_{n \in I} a_n$. Note that
$(a_n)_+=\max(0,a_n) \ge 0$ and $(a_n)_-=\max(0,-a_n) \ge 0$. Since
$0 \le (a_n)_+ \le |a_n|$ and $0 \le (a_n)_- \le |a_n|$ we see that
$\sum_{n \in I} (a_n)_+ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_+$
and similarly for $(a_n)_-$.

This suggests the
definition (cf. Lebesgue integral) 
$\sum_{n \in I} a_n = \sum_{n \in I} (a_n)_+ - \sum_{n \in I} (a_n)_-$.

With this definition, all that remains to be proved is that
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_+ - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_-$ and this follows from
summability and the fact that for each $k$ we have
$\sum_{n \in I_k} a_n = \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_+ - \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_-$.

**Note**: To elaborate the last sentence, recall that I **defined**
$\sum_{n \in I_k} a_n$ to be $\sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_+ - \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_-$, so all that is happening here is the definition is
applied to $I_k$ rather than $I$. Then to finish, note that if $d_k,b_k,c_k$ are summable and satisfy $d_k=b_k-c_k$ then
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k= \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k- \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_k$,
where $d_k = \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n$, $b_k = \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_+$ and $c_k = \sum_{n \in I_k} (a_n)_-$.

Comment: Great answer! But probably you meant bijection $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\to I$, right?

Comment: @ZFR: Correct, I will fix.

Comment: When you wrote that "It is straightforward to show that for any bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N} \to I$ we have $\sum_{n \in I} a_n  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)}$." Do you mean here that $a_n\geq 0$ or not? I am a bit confused

Comment: (+1) This is less fussy, more self-contained, more authoritative, and better connected to the literature than my answer, so it ought to replace it as the accepted answer. (I haven't read @Matematleta's answer yet, because it looks harder to understand than these two, so I reserve judgement on it, for now!) On this answer: am I right in thinking that one can also write $\sum_{n \in I}a_n = s$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists finite $J \subseteq I$ such that $\left\lvert\sum_{n \in J}a_n- s\right\rvert < \epsilon$?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: My apologies, my intent was not to usurp you, but to connect ZFR to the other answer.

Comment: Good Heavens, there is absolutely nothing to apologise for!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: I was thinking something along those lines, but it needs to be refined, because otherwise it would converge to any $s$ that can be formed by taking a finite $J$. I took the 'easy' road out by following the Lebesgue integral construction.

Comment: I think it should be: $\sum_{n \in I}a_n = s$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists finite $J \subseteq I$ such that $\left\lvert\sum_{n \in H}a_n- s\right\rvert < \epsilon$ for all finite $H$ such that $J \subseteq H \subseteq I.$ (*Nobody* expects the Spanish Inquisition! *Amongst* our weaponry are such diverse elements as ...)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: The ordering imposed by $J \subset H$ would seem to make it work. Unfortunately, I often need to stare at definitions for hours before it 'feels right'.

Comment: Because Python suddenly supervened, I forgot to mention that I checked Beardon, *Limits*, Definition 5.2.1b, before posting that last comment, so it might even be right. :)

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence, please? Where did you use summability? Also why $\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}a_n=\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}(a_n)_+-\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}(a_n)_-$ is true? Please.

Comment: I got almost all of your answer but I am bit confused with your last sentence and when you claimed $\sum \limits_{n\in I}a_n=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{\sigma(n)}$

Comment: @ZFR: I added an elaboration of the last sentence and I removed the earlier one (I was going to use it in my proof but found a more straightforward way and forgot to clean up).

Comment: We can apply definition to $\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}a_n$ because it is convergent right since $\sum \limits_{n\in I_k}a_n\leq \sum \limits_{n\in I}a_n<\infty$. Right?

Comment: @ZFR: That is correct. Part of the purpose of my deleted sentencewas to connect the definition of $\sum_{n\in I} a_n$ to the 'normal' definition $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: You really helped me to understand the thing which i did not understand for a long time. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your permanent help!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for the moment that the result is known to be true for
convergent series of non-negative terms.

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
is an absolutely convergent series of real numbers, define
$a_n = b_n - c_n,$ for all $n \geqslant 1,$ where $c_n = 0$ when
$a_n \geqslant 0$ and $b_n = 0$ when $a_n \leqslant 0.$ Then
$|a_n| = b_n + c_n,$ therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ are convergent series of non-negative terms,
therefore:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \in I}a_n & = \sum_{n \in I}b_n - \sum_{n \in I}c_n \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}b_n -
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}c_n \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(
\sum_{n \in I_k}b_n - \sum_{n \in I_k}c_n\right) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}(b_n - c_n) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n.
\end{align*}
So it is enough to prove the result on the assumption that
$a_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n \geqslant 1.$

Given any set $K \subseteq \mathbb{N},$ I shall use the [Iverson
bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation:
$$
[n \in K] =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \in K, \\
0 & \text{if } n \notin K.
\end{cases}
$$
I shall assume that, however the notation $\sum_{n \in K}a_n$ has
been defined, it satisfies the identity:
$$
\sum_{n \in K}a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n[n \in K].
$$
Let $J_k = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots \cup I_k$ ($k = 1, 2, \ldots$).
Because the $I_k$ are disjoint, we have
$$
[n \in J_k] =
[n \in I_1] + [n \in I_2] + \cdots + [n \in I_k],
$$
therefore
$$
\sum_{n \in I_1}a_n + \sum_{n \in I_2}a_n + \cdots +
\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n =
\sum_{n \in J_k}a_n \leqslant \sum_{n \in I}a_n,
$$
therefore
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n \leqslant \sum_{n \in I}a_n,
$$
and the outer infinite sum on the left hand side exists, because its
partial sums are bounded above by the sum on the right hand side.
On the other hand, for all $m \geqslant 1,$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^ma_n[n \in I] & = \sum_{n=1}^ma_n[n \in I_1] +
\sum_{n=1}^ma_n[n \in I_2] + \cdots + \sum_{n=1}^ma_n[n \in I_r] \\
& \leqslant \sum_{n \in I_1}a_n +
\sum_{n \in I_2}a_n + \cdots + \sum_{n \in I_r}a_n \\
& \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n,
\end{align*}
where
$$
r = \max\{k \colon n \leqslant m \text{ for some } n \in I_k\},
$$
therefore
$$
\sum_{n \in I}a_n \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n \in I_k}a_n,
$$
and the two inequalities together prove (*).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I read your answer and I have two questions: 1) I am a bit confused by the definition of $r$? Could you explain it in details, please? 2) Have you ever used that the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: I would define $r$ in this way: for each $n\in I$ s.t. $1\leq n\leq m$ there is $p(n)$ s.t. $n\in I_{p(n)}$ and let's take $r=\max \{p(1),\dots,p(m)\}$ then $[n\in I]=[n\in I_1]+\dots+[n\in I_r]$. Is my reasoning correct? And still I would be happy if you can explain and point the moments where you have used that the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Your definition of $r$ looks right to me, and looks equivalent to mine. Certainly I had much the same idea in mind. I used the absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ when I inferred that the two series of non-negative terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ are convergent. I'm going to try to get some more sleep now, but I'll have another look at the whole thing after lunch, and see if I can make it any clearer. (Assuming it isn't all just a load of dingo's kidneys, of course!)

Comment: I deliberately chose not to write
\begin{gather*}
b_n = \frac{|a_n| + a_n}2 \geqslant 0, \\
c_n = \frac{|a_n| - a_n}2 \geqslant 0,
\end{gather*}
but perhaps it would have been clearer had I done so.

Comment: Perhaps I should also have stated explicitly that the identity I
took to be satisfied by $\sum_{n \in K}a_n$ is a possible definition
of that notation; but it is not the only possible definition; and
you didn't say what definition you were using; so I left it open.

Comment: [Edited version of the first of these comments, which was slightly in error.]
Because the $I_k$ are pairwise disjoint, only finitely many of them
have a non-empty intersection with $\{1,2,\ldots,m\},$ therefore
there exists $r\geqslant1$ such that
$$
I\cap\{1,2,\ldots,m\}=
(I_1\cup I_2\cup\cdots\cup I_r)\cap\{1,2,\ldots,m\},
$$
whence
$$
[n\in I]=[n\in I_1]+[n\in I_2]+\cdots+[n\in I_r]
\quad(n=1,2,\ldots,m).
$$
This directly yields the expression for $\sum_{n=1}^ma_n[n \in I]$
that I used in the answer, without requiring too fussy a definition
of $r.$

Comment: Yeah, the first time when I read your answer I realized that $b_n$ is actually $a_n^+=\max\{a_n,0\}$ and the same for $c_n=-\min\{0,a_n\}$.

Comment: I do not know the definition of $\sum \limits_{n\in K}a_n$ to be honest. I have never thought about this because it seemed to me obvious. But right now I am interested so what is the definition of such sum.

Comment: But the way I suggested to define $r$ is also correct, right? I am really happy that you gave answer to my question. Really nice answer and I accept it as the best. Also I would be thankful if you can explain one more time why absolute converge is so important?

Comment: Also one more stupid question: you wrote that $\sum \limits_{n\in J_k}a_n\leq \sum \limits_{n\in I}a_n$ it is true because $[n\in J_k]\leq [n\in I]$, right?

Comment: **1.** Taking the last question first: yes. **2.** Similarly, the importance of absolute convergence is that $\sum_nb_n$ and $\sum_nc_n$ converge because $0\leqslant b_n\leqslant|a_n|,$ and $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges (and similarly for $\sum_nc_n$ ). **3.** I still think your definition of $r$ is good (and I'm more awake now!). **4.** I don't know of any canonical definition of $\sum_{n\in K}a_n.$ (Was none provided in the context of the problem?) One possibility is to express $K$ uniquely as the image of a strictly increasing sequence $k_1,k_2,\ldots$ and define $\sum_{n\in K}a_n=\sum_ia_{k_i}.$

Comment: 4. No. I came up with this problem when I was solving the following problem from measure theory. If $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$ be a countable set and let $\mathcal{M}$ be $\sigma$-alegbra of all subsets of $A$, i.e. $\mathcal{M}=2^A$ and for each $T\in \mathcal{M}$ define the function $m(T)=\sum \limits_{n:a_n\in T}\frac{1}{2^n}$. And my goal was to show that $m$ is $\sigma$-additive measure. But it is equivalent to the question which I asked, right?!

Comment: (Don't worry, you asked the right question!) Although it puzzles me that the unordered sum notation wasn't defined in the problem, I'm not very surprised, because the topic of unordered sums over countable sets seems to be rather neglected. I looked in a couple of books on measure theory (not a topic I know much about, shamefully), and did a couple of Internet searches, but didn't find any reference on the topic of discrete measures that defines the meaning of such sums.

Comment: Sorry but you could also take a look at this question, please? It is related to what we have discussed. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680110/summation-of-nonnegative-numbers-over-countably-infinite-set

Comment: [MathJax can't be used in chatrooms, so I'll have to risk a slapped wrist!] Your $[n\in T_1\cup T_2]+[n\in T_1\cap T_2]=[n\in T_1]+[n\in  T_2]$ idea looks like the neatest way to answer the other question.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an elementary proof (one without measure theory), that we can adapt from a similar claim in Apostol's Analysis book. Without loss of generality, $I=\mathbb N$. For each $k\in \mathbb N,\ I_k$ may be regarded as a map from some subset $\{1,2,\cdots,\}\subseteq \mathbb N$, to $\{\sigma_k(1),\sigma_k(2),\cdots,\}$ which may or may not be infinite, so $\sigma_k$ is an injective map from the susbet of $\mathbb N$ of the same cardinality as $|I_k|,$ starting at $1$, to the $\textit{set}\ I_k.$ If $|I_k|=j$, extend $I_k$ to all of $\mathbb N$ by mapping $n\in \mathbb N\setminus \{1,2,\cdots, j\}$ to $\mathbb N\setminus \{\sigma_k(1),\sigma_k(2),\cdots, \sigma_k(j)\}$ injectively and defining $a'_n:=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N\setminus \{\sigma_k(1),\sigma_k(2),\cdots, \sigma_k(j)\}$. This construction will not affect any of the sums, so without loss of generality, $I_k$ maps $\mathbb N$ to a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that

$\tag1 I_k\  \text{is injective on}\ \mathbb N $

$\tag2 \text{the range of each}\ I_k \ \text{is a subset of } \ \mathbb N, \text{say}\ P_k $

$\tag3 \text{the}\ P_k\ \text{are disjoint}$

Now put $\tag4 b_k(n)=a_{I_{k}(n)}\ \text{and}\ s_k=\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_k(n)$

which is well-defined by $(1)-(3).$ We have to prove that

$\tag5 \sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k=\sum^\infty_{k=0}s_k$

It's easy to show that the right hand side of this converges absolutely. To find the sum, set $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ large enough so that $\sum^\infty_{k=0}|a_k|-\sum^n_{k=0}|a_k|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as soon as $n>N.$ This implies also that

$\tag6\left|\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k-\sum^n_{k=0}a_k\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Now choose $\{I_1,\cdots, I_r\}$ so that each element of $\{a_1,\dots ,a_N\}$ appears in the sum $\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_{I_{1(n)}}+\cdots +\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_{I_{r(n)}}=s_1+\cdots+ s_r.$ Then, if $n>r,N$ we have

$\tag 7\left|\sum^n_{k=0}s_k-\sum^n_{k=0}a_k\right|<\sum^\infty_{n=N+1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Now $(5)$ folllows from $(6)$ and $(7).$

Comment: I am a bit confused with your definition of $I_k$? Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: $I_k$ is some subset of $\mathbb N$. So it may be regarded as a function on the subset of $\mathbb N$ of the same cardinality. For instance, if $I_k=\{2,5,7\}$ then $I_k$ the function would map $\{1,2,3\}$ to  $\{2,5,7\}$. If $I_k$ is infinite, then it is countable, so there is an injective function from $\mathbb N$ to it. That would be our $I_k$ considered as a function on $\mathbb N.$

Comment: Hmm. I guess that i got you. Also could you show why the RHS of (5) converges absolutely, please?

Comment: Hint: show directly by comparison with $\sum |a_n|$ that $\{s_k\}$ has bounded partial sums.